# Fast way to find unused table through system table info?

Tags: derby

In apache derby, I have to find the unused tables from the log or the system table provided by derby itself. Is there any reference?

I heard that oracle provides the function or the dictionary view for distinguishing unused table or unused index. So does SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "unused". Do you mean: tables that your application does not reference? Is this an application that you did not write? How did the tables come to be in your database?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I am sorry. Yes. unused tables mean that what you said. Applications use the table through jdbc driver. I think derby manages  the access log data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is as follows:

1. Run your application, with derby.language.logStatementText=true: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper43517.html
2. Review your derby.log file, and see which tables are being referenced
3. Compare that list of tables to the total list of tables in your database.

Comment: It is too difficult to extract tables in the log file. I want to use the statistical table and extract the tables through querying the table.